# Есть ли способы облегчения работы со строками в динамических запросах?

Tags: sql-server

Например, есть процедура, которая работает с таблицей название которой передается в процедуру.

Разумеется, в этом случае нужно делать запрос динамическим, так как выборку из переменной делать нельзя(кроме табличных переменных)

И вот тут возникает проблема, если например, в запросе много литералов, то приходится все экранировать двойными кавычками.

Например, `isnull(column,'')` и где-то можно упустить экранирование.

А нет ли какого-нибудь альтернативного синтаксиса или трюков, который облегчает работу с литералами?

Comment: А можно чуть больше контекста? Мне всегда сомнительной казалась идея название _таблицы_ передавать динамически: для каждой таблицы должен быть отдельный набор запросов. А вот набор _колонок_ динамически определять - это нормально.

Comment: Я могу посоветовать статьи, с которыми сам ознакамливался: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html), [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: Можно вообще не думать про экранирование, если динамический запрос сделать его [параметризованным](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) и в нужных местах просто подставить эти параметры, а значения передать в запрос перед вызовом. Кода конечно больше, но текст запроса чище.